# Solr error during bulk load - org.apache.lucene.index.MergePolicy$MergeException

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I'm getting a lot of the following exception while bulk-loading millions of records via sstableloader:

```
ERROR [Lucene Merge Thread #132642] 2014-07-29 00:35:01,252 CassandraDaemon.java (line 199) Exception in thread Thread[Lucene Merge Thread #132642,6,main]
org.apache.lucene.index.MergePolicy$MergeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.handleMergeException(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:545)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:518)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed
        at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.DirectPackedReader.get(DirectPackedReader.java:93)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.BlockPackedReader.get(BlockPackedReader.java:86)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.LongValues.get(LongValues.java:35)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene45.Lucene45DocValuesProducer$5.getOrd(Lucene45DocValuesProducer.java:459)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesConsumer$4$1.setNext(DocValuesConsumer.java:389)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesConsumer$4$1.hasNext(DocValuesConsumer.java:352)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene45.Lucene45DocValuesConsumer.addNumericField(Lucene45DocValuesConsumer.java:141)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene45.Lucene45DocValuesConsumer.addSortedField(Lucene45DocValuesConsumer.java:350)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldDocValuesFormat$FieldsWriter.addSortedField(PerFieldDocValuesFormat.java:116)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesConsumer.mergeSortedField(DocValuesConsumer.java:305)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.mergeDocValues(SegmentMerger.java:197)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.merge(SegmentMerger.java:116)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:4058)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:3655)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.doMerge(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:405)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:482)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Read past EOF (resource: BBIndexInput(name=_13ms5_Lucene45_0.dvd))
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.lucene.store.bytebuffer.ByteBufferIndexInput.switchCurrentBuffer(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:188)
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.lucene.store.bytebuffer.ByteBufferIndexInput.readByte(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:129)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.DataInput.readShort(DataInput.java:77)
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.lucene.store.bytebuffer.ByteBufferIndexInput.readShort(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:89)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.DirectPackedReader.get(DirectPackedReader.java:64)
        ... 15 more
```

I see from the exception trace that it has something to do with Long values and EOF. However, I have no idea what is triggering the error. The SSTable files that I'm trying to import were generated by a Java program (written by me) that uses *org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CQLSSTableWriter*.

The CF schema, Solr schema, and SSTable generator code can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1rpo3ixmz1bg9y2/AAA3aqlfzWEsNIwy79G9dASba

PS:

- I have recently upgraded from DSE 4.1.3 to 4.5.1. I don't remember seeing this error prior to the upgrade
- The cassandra library that is included in the class path of the generator is version 2.0.8. Prior to the DSE upgrade, it uses version 2.0.5 libraries
- DSE topology: 1 DC, 6 solr nodes (vnodes disabled), RF 2
- Other DSE config: LeveledCompaction, LZ4 compression, GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
- Machine specs: CentOS 6.5 x64, JDK 1.7.0_55, hexacore, heap size 120gb (we have specific queries that require this), 128gb total ram

I encountered the error initially in 3 out of 6 nodes. I restarted all of them and I was able to import 150+ million records without an error. But when I left the imports unattended while I sleep, that's when the error resurfaced in 1 out of 6 nodes.

I'm getting quite alarmed now because the number of indexed records in each node (according to Solr admin UI) is smaller by approximately 60,000 records compared to the number of Cassandra rows (according to nodetool cfstats)

**UPDATE:**

Still continuing to experience this. The discrepancy between the number of indexed documents (Solr) and stored documents (Cassandra cfstats) is getting bigger day by day

**UPDATE (2014-08-13):**

Changed the directory factory as suggested by Rock Brain; but the error re-occurred within a few hours of continuous import via sstableloader

**UPDATE (2014-08-14):**

Interestingly, I noticed that I'm actually getting two similar exceptions (with the difference being only the stack trace of the last "caused by":

Exception 1:

```
ERROR [Lucene Merge Thread #24937] 2014-08-14 06:20:32,270 CassandraDaemon.java (line 199) Exception in thread Thread[Lucene Merge Thread #24937,6,main]
org.apache.lucene.index.MergePolicy$MergeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.handleMergeException(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:545)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:518)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed
        at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.DirectPackedReader.get(DirectPackedReader.java:93)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.BlockPackedReader.get(BlockPackedReader.java:86)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.LongValues.get(LongValues.java:35)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene45.Lucene45DocValuesProducer$5.getOrd(Lucene45DocValuesProducer.java:459)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesConsumer$4$1.setNext(DocValuesConsumer.java:389)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesConsumer$4$1.hasNext(DocValuesConsumer.java:352)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene45.Lucene45DocValuesConsumer.addNumericField(Lucene45DocValuesConsumer.java:141)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene45.Lucene45DocValuesConsumer.addSortedField(Lucene45DocValuesConsumer.java:350)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldDocValuesFormat$FieldsWriter.addSortedField(PerFieldDocValuesFormat.java:116)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesConsumer.mergeSortedField(DocValuesConsumer.java:305)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.mergeDocValues(SegmentMerger.java:197)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.merge(SegmentMerger.java:116)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:4058)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:3655)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.doMerge(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:405)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:482)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Read past EOF (resource: BBIndexInput(name=_67nex_Lucene45_0.dvd))
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.lucene.store.bytebuffer.ByteBufferIndexInput.switchCurrentBuffer(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:188)
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.lucene.store.bytebuffer.ByteBufferIndexInput.readByte(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:129)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.DirectPackedReader.get(DirectPackedReader.java:64)
        ... 15 more
```

Exception 2 (exactly the same as the original exception on top of this post):

```
ERROR [Lucene Merge Thread #24936] 2014-08-14 06:20:34,694 CassandraDaemon.java (line 199) Exception in thread Thread[Lucene Merge Thread #24936,6,main]
org.apache.lucene.index.MergePolicy$MergeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.handleMergeException(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:545)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:518)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed
        at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.DirectPackedReader.get(DirectPackedReader.java:93)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.BlockPackedReader.get(BlockPackedReader.java:86)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.LongValues.get(LongValues.java:35)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene45.Lucene45DocValuesProducer$5.getOrd(Lucene45DocValuesProducer.java:459)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesConsumer$4$1.setNext(DocValuesConsumer.java:389)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesConsumer$4$1.hasNext(DocValuesConsumer.java:352)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene45.Lucene45DocValuesConsumer.addNumericField(Lucene45DocValuesConsumer.java:141)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene45.Lucene45DocValuesConsumer.addSortedField(Lucene45DocValuesConsumer.java:350)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldDocValuesFormat$FieldsWriter.addSortedField(PerFieldDocValuesFormat.java:116)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesConsumer.mergeSortedField(DocValuesConsumer.java:305)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.mergeDocValues(SegmentMerger.java:197)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.merge(SegmentMerger.java:116)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:4058)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:3655)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.doMerge(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:405)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:482)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Read past EOF (resource: BBIndexInput(name=_67fvk_Lucene45_0.dvd))
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.lucene.store.bytebuffer.ByteBufferIndexInput.switchCurrentBuffer(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:188)
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.lucene.store.bytebuffer.ByteBufferIndexInput.readByte(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:129)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.DataInput.readShort(DataInput.java:77)
        at com.datastax.bdp.search.lucene.store.bytebuffer.ByteBufferIndexInput.readShort(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:89)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.DirectPackedReader.get(DirectPackedReader.java:64)
        ... 15 more
```

**UPDATE part 2 (2014-08-14):**

example RELOAD warning:

```
 WARN [http-8983-2] 2014-08-14 08:31:28,828 CassandraCoreContainer.java (line 739) Too much waiting for new searcher...
 WARN [http-8983-2] 2014-08-14 08:31:28,831 SolrCores.java (line 375) Tried to remove core myks.mycf from pendingCoreOps and it wasn't there.
 INFO [http-8983-2] 2014-08-14 08:31:28,832 StorageService.java (line 2644) Starting repair command #3, repairing 0 ranges for keyspace solr_admin
 INFO [http-8983-2] 2014-08-14 08:31:28,835 SolrDispatchFilter.java (line 672) [admin] webapp=null path=/admin/cores params={slave=true&deleteAll=false&name=myks.mycf&distributed=false&action=RELOAD&reindex=false&core=myks.mycf&wt=javabin&version=2} status=0 QTime=61640
```

**UPDATE (2014-08-23):**

I wasn't able to reproduce the exception anymore after re-doing the suggested **workaround**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your solrconfig.xml for all your cores: swap the `directoryFactory` from `com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.index.solr.DSENRTCachingDirectoryFactory` to `solr.MMapDirectoryFactory`.

Also, what OS, JVM version is being used, how many CPUs, heap size, total available memory.  How many minutes/hours into the loading does the error occur.

Comment: CentOS 6.5 x64, JDK 1.7.0_55, hexacore, heap size 120gb (we have specific queries that require this), 128gb total ram. The error appears randomly

Comment: Ok thanks.  This issue is being worked on for resolution.  A workaround is to use 'solr.MMapDirectoryFactory' instead.

Comment: Can you give a brief explanation as to what is going on? i.e. what is the cause? Is this specific to DSE 4.5? Do I need to reindex? (because I'm already seeing a large discrepancy between the "number of keys" from nodetool cfstats and "numDocs" from Solr admin UI)

Comment: Also, can the directory factory be changed on-the-fly from "com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.index.solr.DSENRTCachingDirectoryFactory" to "solr.MMapDirectoryFactory" as you suggest? We already have data in our cluster - we don't want to start over

Comment: The issue does not seem to be specific to particular version of DSE.  Reindexing should not be necessary as Lucene segments are written once, then merged.  The error is occurring during a merge, which means the raw indexes still exist.  However if there seems to be data loss then re-indexing may be required.

Comment: The directory factory may be changed on the fly without re-indexing.

Comment: Changed the directory factory as suggested; but the error re-occurred within a few hours of continuous import via sstableloader

Comment: Can you post the exception?  Was RELOAD done after uploading the new solrconfig.xml?

Comment: Same exception as in the original post. Once triggered in one machine, it will continuously be thrown in that machine (thus, flooding the system.log). Out of 6 nodes, I currently have 2 where the exception has been triggered. Regarding the suggested fix: I changed the directory factory setting in solrconfig.xml, POSTed the file to all cores, and RELOADed all cores with reindex=false & deleteAll=false

Comment: The exception should be different and will help in identifying the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, the exception really is the same as before. I will give it another try (i.e. repost the config and reload the cores), although I honestly doubt that this will change anything. I will let you know when I manage to trigger the exception again

Comment: On an unrelated note: I noticed that RELOAD fails when password authentication is enabled in Cassandra. I had to disable authentication just to make node-to-node RELOAD work (otherwise, only the node where the RELOAD request was sent to will successfully reload). Is there a solution for it? (to clarify: I noticed and addressed this already in my first reload attempt; this has nothing to do with the same exception being thrown again)

Comment: I have just reposted the config and reloaded the cores. I haven't resumed the imports yet; but I will post a comment here as soon as the exception is triggered again. I did notice, however, that during reload, some nodes had the following "WARN" log printed to system.log saying "Too much waiting for new searcher..." and "Tried to remove core myks.mycf from pendingCoreOps and it wasn't there". The status code is still 0 nonetheless. (See updated OP for a formatted log)

Comment: The "Too much waiting for new searcher.." doesn't sound good, can you post the entire exception?

Comment: Accepted your suggested workaround as an answer. Kindly update your post with an official bug report link (regarding DSENRTCachingDirectoryFactory) to make it easier for me and other users to track the status of the issue

Comment: @RockBrain I'm in the process of adding a new node to my Solr cluster and I'm seeing the same stack trace accompanied by Cassandra write timeouts. I just updated solrconfig to use `solr.MMapDirectoryFactory` (and reloaded) but this hasn't helped.

Comment: @advait Can you post the exception?